# How to make SQLite trigger modify existing string

Tags: sqlite, triggers

I have an SQLite table with a `STRING` type column named "NOTES". I want to create a trigger that automatically updates the content of the NOTES column, but doesn't replace it entirely.

The following does not work, I do not see errors, the NOTES column just never gets updated.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AlterNote 
    AFTER INSERT ON MyTable 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN UPDATE MyTable 
        SET NOTES= NOTES || 'DATEMODIFIED: ' || date('now')
        WHERE rowid=NEW.rowid; 
    END;
```

This does work presumably because I am no longer referencing the thing I'm updating:

```
CREATE TRIGGER AlterNote 
    AFTER INSERT ON MyTable 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN UPDATE MyTable 
        SET NOTES= 'DATEMODIFIED: ' || date('now')
        WHERE rowid=NEW.rowid; 
    END;
```

Is there a way to do this? Basically NOTES=NOTES+"blah"

Comment: Atilla's answer is correct. My issue was that I had NULL strings, which you cannot add other strings onto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use new.COLUMN_NAME syntax.

```
CREATE TRIGGER AlterNote 
    AFTER INSERT ON MyTable 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN UPDATE MyTable 
        SET NOTES= new.Notes || ',DATEMODIFIED: ' || date('now')
        WHERE rowid=NEW.rowid; 
    END;
```

See example run.

```
sqlite>
sqlite> create table mytable(Notes text);
sqlite> insert into mytable(Notes) Values('aa');
sqlite> select * from mytable;
aa
sqlite> CREATE TRIGGER AlterNote
   ...>     AFTER INSERT ON MyTable
   ...>     FOR EACH ROW
   ...>     BEGIN UPDATE MyTable
   ...>         SET NOTES= new.Notes || ',DATEMODIFIED: ' || date('now')
   ...>         WHERE rowid=NEW.rowid;
   ...>     END;
sqlite>
sqlite>
sqlite>
sqlite>
sqlite> insert into mytable(Notes) Values('aa2');
sqlite> select * from mytable;
aa
aa2,DATEMODIFIED: 2014-12-22
```